# Global Variables in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to use a FIFO queue of size 2 to store elements of a datastream. At any instance, I need the previous element that came in the stream and not the current element. To do this, I have created a queue outside the stream code and I am enqueuing the current element. When my queue has two elements, I dequeue it and use the first element.

The problem I am facing is that I am not able to enqueue the queue as it is declared outside my stream code. I guess this is because streaming use multiple JVMs and my queue would be declared in one JVM.

Below is a sample code:

```
val queue = Queue[Array[Double]]() //Global Queue

val ws = dataStream.map(row => {
    queue.enqueue(row)
    println(queue.size) //Prints 0 always
    if(queue.size == 2){
        result = operate(queue(0))
        queue.dequeue
    }
    result
})
```

Here, nothing is getting enqueued and the size of the queue is always 0. 
Is there a way we can create global variables in Flink which are distributed across all the JVMs? If not, is there any other way to implement this logic?

Comment: Your note:
<<I guess this is because streaming use multiple JVMs>>
should be on the right direction. 
How do you ensure that the queue is correctly handled between multiple taskManagers and in case of failures? You should probably implement it in a state...

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly enough, it worked when I replaced `Queue` with Scala `List`.

Comment: are you sure this will work on a distributed cluster?

Comment: @enrico not sure. Not working on this project anymore.. If you have any ideas, please share.